# SET Group_CONCAT size using MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I am new to SQL injection and I am trying to do

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000
```

inside SQL injection but i am geting SQL Error: Here is what i am trying

```
index.php?id=15 union all select 1,2,3;SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000
```

I have seen this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942901/mysql-group-concat-max-len-in-a-query/37726578), but i am not able to run this.

Comment: 1.First run this query not in injection env and make sure it’s running.
2. on the second time you will call it, it won’t be set because it’s new session, you can try to set it to global instead of session.

Comment: i tried it on phpmyadmin and its workng fine, But during SQL injection it gives me error

Comment: what about 2? 
what is the error that it gives you?

Comment: If i run `SET Global group_concat_max_len = 10000` on phpmyadmin It works fine,  but this query is not working when combined with another query. Not even on phpmyadmin. i am trying ` select * from attendance where id = 15 UNION SET  Global group_concat_max_len = 10000`
Error msg is here:
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET global group_concat_max_len=30000' at line 1